# Model w/ array of strings in Sails / Waterline

Tags: javascript, sails.js, waterline

Does sails / waterline offer a declarative way to enforce that elements of an array in my model are of type string?  Or must I write code to perform this validation?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that this can be accomplished by adding a custom type to the model (described in the [Waterline readme](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline)):

```
module.exports = {
    types: {
        stringArray: function(array){
            if (!Array.isArray(array)) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return array.every(function (value) {
                    return typeof(value) === "string"
                });
            }
        }
    },
    attributes: {
        someArrayOfStrings : {
            type: 'array',
            stringArray: true
        }
    }
};
```

Custom validation code is required, but at least this approach works with the validation engine and allows for declarative validation in the model.

Comment: array type is a little dummy not? When I need to check the type every time used. :/

Comment: I am unable to use array/other types. I have to use `type: json` and use a type validator. I am also not able to use minLength, maxLength etc. What waterline version are you using? I am using waterline v0.13.5. Need some help if can check this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53587393/sails-min-max-minlength-maxlength-for-number-and-string-types-gives-usererror

Answer (score 1):

As far as I have been able to tell there is no way to do this in the model declaration. You can easily accomplish it in the "beforeValidate" callback, however.

If you note in the comments of the code snippet [here](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/ORM/Lifecyclecallbacks.html), passing anything to the callback in a lifecycle callback will trigger an error, so this little bit of code is all you need to validate that your array contains only strings:

```
beforeValidate: function (values, cb) {

  values.arrOfStrings.forEach(function(str) {
    if (typeof(str) != "string") {
      cb("err: arrOfStrings must contain only strings");
    }
  }

  cb()
}
```

Comment: NOTE that you're using `forEach` which is async, so potentially both of these callbacks will be called. The JS engine is gonna continue right over the forEach, call `cb()` and, say, the last item in the array triggers the inequality -- `cb` is now called twice. So refactor this to a `for(i)` loop if you want the engine to stay at the iteration until its finished.