# Sails min, max, minLength, maxLength for number and string types gives userError

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, waterline, sails-mongo

I am using waterline v0.13.5 package with expressjs.

- I get an user error `{ userError: The attribute 'str' on the 'action' model contains invalid properties. The property 'minLength' isn't a recognized property.` when trying to use min, max (with number type) and minLength, maxLength (with string type).
- This same type of error is also  received with `isIn` property when used like this `"isIn": [1,2,3]`.
- `autoPK: true` also doesnt work as expected. It forces me to define _id in the model attributes definition and primaryKey key in the extend definition options.
- I am also not able to get the `types` validator function triggered in general. The function `isStringType` is not triggered when there is a entry into mongodb.

But the documentation for sails v1.0 says it can be done. This error is  occuring when I am trying to extend/create the model using the `Waterline.Collection.extend` function. I can specify manually the min and max but want to keep it dynamic for different attributes properties. So that is not a viable option.

```
waterline.registerModel(Waterline.Collection.extend({
    identity: 'action',
    datastore: 'recAuth',
    schema: true,
    tableName: 'action',
    autoPK: true,
    primaryKey: '_id',
    types: {
        isStringType: function (v) { 
           console.log('String validator triggered');
           return typeof v === 'string';
        }
    },
    attributes: {
        "_id": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "str": {
            "type": "string",
            "required": true,
            "minLength": 12,
            "isStringType": true
        }
    }
}));
```